# JMETER ERROR o.a.j.u.SSLManager: Problem loading keystore: No key(s) found java.lang.NullPointerException: No key(s) found

Tags: java, ssl, https, jmeter

I am trying to run jmeter test reaching https server,so I am using client side keystore with certificate in it, but getting this -  ERROR o.a.j.u.SSLManager: Problem loading keystore: No key(s) found java.lang.NullPointerException: No key(s) found.

```
    o.a.j.u.JsseSSLManager: SSL session context: per-thread
2022-04-07 17:22:54,741 INFO o.a.j.u.SSLManager: JmeterKeyStore Location: client.jks type JKS
2022-04-07 17:22:54,744 INFO o.a.j.u.SSLManager: KeyStore created OK
2022-04-07 17:22:54,758 ERROR o.a.j.u.SSLManager: Problem loading keystore: No key(s) found
java.lang.NullPointerException: No key(s) found
                at java.util.Objects.requireNonNull(Objects.java:228) ~[?:1.8.0_232]
                at org.apache.jmeter.util.keystore.JmeterKeyStore.load(JmeterKeyStore.java:138) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.2.1]
                at org.apache.jmeter.util.SSLManager.getKeyStore(SSLManager.java:141) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.2.1]
                at org.apache.jmeter.util.SSLManager.configureKeystore(SSLManager.java:309) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.2.1]
                at org.apache.jmeter.config.KeystoreConfig.testStarted(KeystoreConfig.java:99) [ApacheJMeter_components.jar:5.2.1]
                at org.apache.jmeter.config.KeystoreConfig.testStarted(KeystoreConfig.java:63) [ApacheJMeter_components.jar:5.2.1]
                at org.apache.jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine.notifyTestListenersOfStart(StandardJMeterEngine.java:206) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.2.1]
                at org.apache.jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine.run(StandardJMeterEngine.java:381) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.2.1]
                at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:819) [?:1.8.0_232]
```

Keystore is of JKS type with one certificate.cer inside.

System.properties updated with correct path and password to client keystore.
I checked certificate (1) is in keystore.
What else can be checked?

Comment: Do you have a private key in there as well? Note that your question has almost no relevant information in it, so without the full stacktrace, key store contents etc. there is very little we can hint at.

Comment: No, there is only certificate.cer

Comment: There are two options: either you have a trusted certificate that completes a trust path to verify the other side's certificate, or you have a certificate / key combination to authenticate to the other side. The error seems to indicate that the software expects the latter. Do you have client authentication enabled? What properties have been set?

Comment: This is private network and proxy is used as well. Looking at logs it seems like there is no problem connecting to proxy server, connection established, but when it goes to host connection which is https it starts SSL context and fails with above mentioned exception. Can something depend on alias? Or it can be any random value..

Comment: I'd put the private key and certificate under the same alias. Not sure anymore if it will otherwise try and look up the key using the modulus that is shared between the public key in the certificate and private key (assuming RSA is used).

Comment: Oh, yeah, and you'd better include all certificates in the chain, not just the final certificate, not including the root certificate. Otherwise the other party might not find intermediate CA certs, and therefore cannot establish a trust path. Client cert first, CA certs later.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes: it's not so much the _same_ alias; in JKS format a [PrivateKeyEntry](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/security/KeyStore.html) is a single object, associated with an alias, that contains the privatekey AND the cert CHAIN. In contrast in PKCS12 format corresponding privatekey and cert are linked by localkeyid, while friendlyname is used for the alias; in PKCS11 privatekey and cert both use some identity field(s) but I don't recall which.

Answer (score 0):

You can [check whether the certificate is present in the keystore](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1213/wls/SECMG/keytool-summary-appx.htm#SECMG818) by running the following command:

```
keytool -v -list -keystore /path/to/your/client.jks
```

In case if you want to check the presence of the specific alias in case if there are multiple certificates - you can also supply the alias name:

```
keytool -list -keystore /path/to/your/client.jks -alias your-alias-here
```

or use a GUI-based tool like [KeyStore Explorer](https://keystore-explorer.org/)

once you put the certificate into the keystore or provide a valid alias the at least this error will go away

More information: [How to Set Your JMeter Load Test to Use Client Side Certificates](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/client-side-performance-testing-using-jmeter)

Comment: I checked the keystore and there is certificate inside for sure. I do not know, what means valid alias in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Noticed that, test are running OK however it still complains Keys not found in keystore.

Comment: This doesn't seem to offer a solution. Best hit the edit button and update the question instead or post a comment. Beware that [so] usually down votes these kind of posts..